# Can Hudson check out from multiple SCMs?

Tags: plugins, hudson, version-control

Due to some politics at work we have our project in two different SCMs, SVN and Dimensions.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a plugin available that would change Hudson's radio buttons into checkboxes to allow me to configure multiple SCM repositories in the project's config on hudson?

Answer (score 2):

No it can't. However, the svn plugin allows you to check out from several locations.

A work around would be to use a (pre-) build step to check out from your repositories using a command line tool.

Comment: +1 for that. Another solution would be to cascade jobs, i.e. have one (check out) job be triggered by svn and a downstream (check-out) job that gets stuff from dimensions and then yet another downstream job that performs the actual build.

Comment: Disadvantage cascading the jobs like jhwist suggested is, that you need to share jobs between jobs. That is fine as long you only trigger jobs by a timer (e.g. nightly builds). If you query the SCMs for changes on a regular basis, you can run into conflicts that two jobs want to access the same workspace. That story won't end pretty.

Comment: If you cascade the jobs, it would be best to archive the files into an artifact to avoid concurrent access on the workspace.

Comment: Taking Michaels comment into account. The best setup would be to have two jobs. One that builds the SVN parts the second one builds the Dimension parts. Both jobs should archive the artifacts and than you can use the join plugin (if needed), so that a third job gets triggered after the first two jobs are done and compiles the final artifacts from the artifacts from the first two jobs.