# Is it possible to pre-create a virtualenv for use in hudson builds?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, hudson, virtualenv, pip

I'm following the outline of the hudson/python/virtualenv CI solution [described at heisel.org](http://heisel.org/blog/2009/11/21/django-hudson/) but one step of this is really chafing, and that's the part where the virtualenv, created just for the CI run, is configured:

```
pip install -q -E ./ve -r requirements.pip
pip install -q -E ./ve -r requirements-test.pip
```

This takes an inordinate amount of time to run, and every time a source file changes we'll end up re-downloading what amounts to a significant amount of data.

Is it possible to create template workspaces in Hudson, so that instead of checking out into a bare workspace it checks out into one that is pre-prepared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple options:

1. Have an archive in your source repository that blows up into the
   virtualenv/pip install. You'll need to make the virtualenv starting point relocatable.
2. Use whatever SCM option is appropriate to not wipe out the workspace
   between builds (e.g. Use svn update, or don't check Mercurial's Clean Build
   option). Then keep the install commands in your build script, but put them in
   under an `if` statement so they are only run (for example) if a `.pip_installed` file is not present, or if a build parameter is set.
3. You might be able to get the [Clone Workspace](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin) plugin to do what you
   want. But that's an alternative SCM, which I'm guessing you probably don't
   want since Hudson won't check out from multiple SCMs (see [this previous
   question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976720/can-hudson-check-out-from-multiple-scms) for some ideas about working around this).

It's probably also a good idea to set up your pip configuration to pull from a
local cache of packages.

```
pip -f http://localhost/packages/
```

Answer (score 0):

An enhancement is to package the virtualenv in an archive named by the hash of the requirements file. If the requirements file has not changed since the last build, just extract the archive into an empty virtualenv directory. If the requirements file has changed, an archive won't yet exist, so you run pip install to build the environment and then store it in a new archive.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new venv per workspace then you only really have to install all the deps once at the beggining so subsequent builds are much faster. See my post for a script I wrote to help out:

["Pretty" Continuous Integration for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225598/pretty-continuous-integration-for-python/5119040#5119040)